# Why does this query does not work on my blade file?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to do a SELECT * query to a table, It has a uniquerparameter column that I need to use to filter the data... and this error shows up:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL 
 Server]Conversion failed when converting from a character string to 
  uniqueidentifier. (SQL: select * from [vw_DigitalLibrary_History] where 
 [ManualBook_SectionParagraphGlobalID] =  '588237FB-7A69-40F8-AE85- 
 9596EEF44894') (View: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\digital- 
 library\resources\views\admin\going_live.blade.php)
```

This the uniqueidentifier column: ManualBook_SectionParagraphGlobalID

The same query that gets generated using laravel and its on the error:

```
select * from [vw_DigitalLibrary_History] where 
 [ManualBook_SectionParagraphGlobalID] =  '588237FB-7A69-40F8-AE85- 
 9596EEF44894'
```

works like a charm on SQL management studio

I have tried this:

```
$FutureHist = App\History::where('ManualBook_SectionParagraphGlobalID', $split[1])->limit(1)->get();
```

tried to CONVERT it but I think it reaches the SQL server as a string

```
$split = explode("=", $Future[0]["Filter"]);

$FutureHist = App\History::where('ManualBook_SectionParagraphGlobalID', TRY_CONVERT($split[1], uniqueidentifier))->limit(1)->get();
```

I expect the $FutureHist variable to get the results but I havent found a way to bypass this error.

SOLUTION:
For the poor souls out there facing this same error you can do as dparoli said, but there was some problems with the '' part.. this is how you should put it

```
$FutureHist = App\History::whereRaw("ManualBook_SectionParagraphGlobalID = CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, ".$split[1].")")
    ->limit(1)->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you can try with a whereRaw() and a cast like you did, i.e.:

```
App\History::whereRaw("ManualBook_SectionParagraphGlobalID = CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, '588237FB-7A69-40F8-AE85-9596EEF44894')")
    ->limit(1)->get();
```

Or with the variable expansion:

```
App\History::whereRaw("ManualBook_SectionParagraphGlobalID = CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, '$split[1]')")
    ->limit(1)->get();
```

Comment: I was just trying the raw part of the querys when you answered haha, I have like 4 hours on this part alone... thanks so much dude.